# Coordinates of regular octagon

Tags: analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

There are coordinates of two vertices in a regular octagon $$\{A_0,A_1,...,A_7\}$$

with Cartesian coordinates $A_0 = (2,-4)$, $A_2 = (0,0)$.

The task is to find coordinates of all other vertices.

---

I have found coordinates of centre of a circle which is inscribed by octagon $S=(-1,-3)$ by the following formula
$$A_k-S = (A_0-S)(\cos(2k\pi/8) + i\sin(2k\pi/8))=$$

$$=A_k-S = (A_0-S)(\cos(k\pi/4) + i\sin(k\pi/4)),\tag 1$$ where $S = a+ib$
for $k=2$ it's
$$A_k-S = (A_0-S)(\cos(2\pi/4) + i\sin(2\pi/4))\tag 2$$
$$0-a-bi = (2-4i-a-bi)(\cos(\pi/2) + i\sin(\pi/2))$$
$$-a-bi = (2-4i-a-bi)i$$
$$0 = 2i+4-ai+b+a+bi$$

$a+b+4 = 0$ and $-a+b+2 = 0$ , $a = -1$, $b=-3$ , then $S=(-1,-3)$
, but geometrically it doesn't make any sense. Which mistake I have done?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Why are you saying that your solution does not have geometrical sense?

Comment: I know it's right but I don't know how to compute coordinates for A_1. In GeoGebra it is A_1=(1.83,-1.59) I think it is A_1=(2*sqrt(2)-1,sqrt(2)-3)) but it's strange, because I always get A_1=(3*sqrt(2)-1,sqrt(2)-3) from (2,-4)*R_(45 degrees)+(-1,-3). What's wrong with that, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Having learned the coordinates of $S$ you can use the formula you have been using:
$$A_k = (A_0-S)(\cos(k\pi/4) + i\sin(k\pi/4))+S.$$

but with $k=1$.